# Removing WWW from Subdomain for Staging Server via httpd.conf

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, domain-name-system, subdomain, httpd

I am trying to set up a staging server to run as a sub-domain of my production server and I'm running into a small problem.

I have my production server hosted on a RackSpace virtual machine.  I cloned this machine to use as my staging server.  I also added `A` records to direct the sub-domain address to this new virtual machine.

I want to be able to access this staging server by typing `staging.domain.com`, but that currently doesn't work.  The workaround that I've found to work is typing `www.staging.domain.com`. Note the extra `www` in front of the sub-domain.

My directory structure is such that in my project directory I have a `public_html` directory (which obviously houses the  publicly viewable files) and a `private` (which houses more of the back-end code).  I want to have Apache serve `/var/www/staging.domain.com/public_html/index.php` as the default file when I visit `staging.domain.com`.

As stated, I am currently only able to get what I want by visiting `www.staging.domain.com`.  When I visit `staging.domain.com` I am redirected to `www.staging.domain.com/staging.domain.com/public_html`.

My httpd.conf is set up as follows (I am definitely not an expert in configuration of this file):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # General Server Setup
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ServerName  www.staging.domain.com
    ServerAlias staging.domain.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    DocumentRoot /var/www/staging.domain.com/public_html
    <Directory /var/www/staging.domain.com/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I am pretty sure that the redirect I spoke of earlier is happening because of my specified `DocumentRoot` in this file.

Also, I have tried many different combinations of `CNAME` and `A` records trying to get this to work, but I'm open to any other suggestions you might have.

#### Update

I don't have anything specified for my `.htaccess` file, so that shouldn't be effecting anything.

My current DNS record for this server are:

```
Type    Name                      Content                   TTL
 A       staging.domain.com        XX.XX.XX.XX(server IP)    300
 A       www.staging.domain.com    XX.XX.XX.XX(server IP)    300
```

There is really no additional information that I've configured that I can think of to share with you.  If you can think of anything just ask.

Comment: At least from the config that you've shown us, Apache isn't doing that redirect.  Check your code?

Comment: @ShaneMadden I have added some new information.  As far as your statement about Apache, the code is copied verbatim (minus the domain name of course).

Comment: As far as "code" I mean your php code.  Unless there's some config outside of that `VirtualHost`, then Apache isn't the cause of that redirect.  Though now that I think about it, check `/var/www` for an `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @ShaneMadden +1 for being awesome.  `/var/www/.htaccess` was the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a default `.htaccess` file in the `/var/www/` directory that was causing this action.  I removed it as suggested by @Shane_Madden which fixed the problem.